# Strange webpage display

Tags: php, html, browser

I have made a webpage and doing testing in different browsers. In Chrome, everything is okay. But in IE, in some pages, at their ends, a few words are used to repeat themselves, far away.

When I use cursor to highlight the repeated words, the original words far away are also being highlighted.

May experts teach me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Maybe some IE bugs but we can't help without information.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some kind of sample, maybe even a link to the page hosted somewhere?  Your description, unfortunately, is not enough to go on.

Comment: some code or example would be nice.

Comment: Could you give us a link to this webpage? or at least post your code

Comment: How can we know what's wrong without code or a link??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably its because of CSS file which you have made for all explorers the same. You will need to change the CSS file according to your browser.
If you have already done it then sample or image/code of your web page is required to find
the actual problem and then the solution.

Comment: This is just a shoot in the dark, yoi know..

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Actually I have prepared a print screen but since I do not have enough marks I cannot paste it... I shall post the photo again when I have 10 marks.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a photo here:

Comment: http://cheaper.com.hk/displayproblem.jpg

Comment: yeah i have seen the picture. Is it a dynamic or static site? Well in both cases there is a problem with the code recheck the code you ll get the error. I think you are repeating the words some where.

Comment: it's a dynamic site... but if it is code error, I believe such repeat will appear in chrome as well! Also, it's normal in iPhone...

Comment: Good Point. Then you think its error in IE? Try on firefox or some other.

Comment: @Ham Can you post some code? can you give us a url? it's IMPOSSIBLE like this